# Why do I get the "type mismatch" error when running the macro?

Tags: excel, vba

It's my first time doing VBA Macro and I'm having a hard time understanding the problem.

I'm trying to filter and color cells with specific values but when I try running the code it says 'Type mismatch'.

```
Dim count, i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim count, i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

count = ws.Cells(Rows.count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
i = 2

Do While i <= count

If Cells(i, 5).Value = "#N/A" _
Or Cells(i, 5).Value = "#Ref" _
Or Cells(i, 5).Value = "Null" _
Or Cells(i, 5).Value = "" _
Or Cells(i, 5).Value = "#DIV/0!" _
Or Cells(i, 5).Value = "" _
Or Cells(i, 5).Value Like "*-*" Then

Cells(i, 5).Interior.Color = RGB(38, 201, 218)

End If


i = i + 1

Loop

ws.Range("E1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=RGB(38, 201, 218), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
```

And when I click the debug it highlights the If statements. Is there a way to solve this or is there a better way to filter these values while highlighting them in VBA?

Comment: Can you share some info, that is the value of i when it errors?  I think it's because its go to an error cell, look at `IsError` for the error checking

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, more of a expanded comment.

```
If IsError(Cells(i, 5)) Then
    Cells(i, 5).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
ElseIf Cells(i, 5).Value = "" Then
    Cells(i, 5).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
Else
    Cells(i, 5).Interior.Color = xlNone
End If
```

Also, this to sift the errors https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/cell-error-values

Answer (score 1):

First problem: If your cell contain an error, it doesn't contain the string `"#N/A"` or  `"#Ref"`, it contains a special value. What you see is only a visual representation of that error. If you want to check for an error within Excel, you should use the function `IsError`. That would lead to (*wait, don't use that!*):

```
If isError(Cells(i, 5).Value)
Or Cells(i, 5).Value = "Null" _
Or Cells(i, 5).Value = "" _
Or Cells(i, 5).Value Like "*-*" Then
```

Second problem: In VBA, there is no optimization for a conditional statement, VBA will always evaluate all parts. Your If-statement contains several conditions, combined with `Or`. While other programming languages quit evaluating when one condition makes the whole expression true, VBA will continue to evaluate all conditions.

Now if you have an error in a cell and you would use the code above, you will still get a type mismatch error: You cannot compare an error with a string. The condition `isError(Cells(i, 5).Value)` will get True, but VBA will continue to compare the cell content with strings and that gives you the mismatch. You need a way to split your If-statement.

Some more remarks: You are assigning the worksheet you want to work with to variable `ws`, but you are not using it. You will need to qualify every single usage of `Cells` (write `ws.Cells(i, 5)`, else VBA will assume you are working with the Active Sheet, and that may or may not be Sheet1. Usually, this is done with a `With`-statement (note all the leading dots).

Your declaration statement is flawed (a common mistake in VBA), you will need to specify the type for every variable. In your case, `Count` will be of type `Variant`, not `Long`. No problem here, but in other cases it is, so make it a habit to declare all variables correctly.

You should use a `For`-Loop rather than a `Do While`.

```
Dim count As Long, i As Long
With ws
    count = .Cells(.Rows.count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 to count
        Dim markCell as boolean
        If isError(.Cells(i, 5).Value) Then
            markCell = True       
        ElseIf .Cells(i, 5) = "Null" _
        Or .Cells(i, 5).Value = "" _
        Or .Cells(i, 5).Value Like "*-*" Then
            markCell = True
        Else
            markCell = False
        End If
        If markCell Then
            .Cells(i, 5).Interior.Color = RGB(38, 201, 218)
        End If
   Next i
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check for specific errors you first need to check if there are errors with `IsError`. You cannot check for an error and a value in one condition:

```
Do While i <= count
    Dim Condition As Boolean
    Condition = False  ' initialize when in a loop!
    
    If IsError(Cells(i, 5).Value) Then
        If Cells(i, 5).Value = CVErr(xlErrNA) _
             Or Cells(i, 5).Value = CVErr(xlErrRef) _
             Or Cells(i, 5).Value = CVErr(xlErrNull) _
             Or Cells(i, 5).Value = CVErr(xlErrDiv0) Then
                 Condition = True
        End If
    ElseIf Cells(i, 5).Value = "" Or Cells(i, 5).Value Like "*-*" Then
        Condition = True
    End If
    
    If Condition = True Then
        Cells(i, 5).Interior.Color = RGB(38, 201, 218)
    End If
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

### Filter By Color

```vb
Sub FilterByColor()

    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const Col As String = "E"
    Dim FilterColor As Long: FilterColor = RGB(38, 201, 218)

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    If ws.FilterMode Then ws.ShowAllData ' remove any filters
    
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim rgData As Range ' data range; no header
    Set rgData = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, Col), ws.Cells(lRow, Col))
    rgData.Interior.Color = xlNone ' remove all colors
    
    Dim rgColor As Range ' the combined range to be colored
    Dim DataCell As Range ' each cell of the data range
    Dim cString As String
    Dim DoColor As Boolean
    
    For Each DataCell In rgData.Cells
        If IsError(DataCell) Then ' error value
            DoColor = True
        Else
            cString = CStr(DataCell.Value)
            If Len(cString) = 0 Then ' blank
                DoColor = True
            Else
                If InStr(1, cString, "-") > 0 Then ' contains a minus ('-')
                    DoColor = True
                End If
            End If
        End If
        If DoColor Then
            If rgColor Is Nothing Then ' combine cells into a range
                Set rgColor = DataCell
            Else
                Set rgColor = Union(rgColor, DataCell)
            End If
            DoColor = False ' don't forget to reset
        End If
    Next DataCell
        
    If rgColor Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    rgColor.Interior.Color = FilterColor ' apply color in one go
    
    Dim rgTable As Range ' table range; header included
    Set rgTable = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, Col), ws.Cells(lRow, Col))
    
    rgTable.AutoFilter 1, FilterColor, xlFilterCellColor
    
    ' To delete the rows, you could continue with e.g.:
'    rgData.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
'    ws.AutoFilterMode = False ' remove 'AutoFilter'
    
End Sub
```